# Google Map using Fancybox working Firefox perfectly but Other Browsers it Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

See the this for q demo: [Try it](http://logz.comeze.com/demo/popup.php)

I have one problem in my development. I used below Script to load the *Fancybox Popup*.

After clicking `Submit` button, it would open another popup which contains a map.
That map is working perfectly on Firefox, however  it does not work on other browsers.

I must be able to get that map working on all current browsers. Please guide me to solve this problem

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {   
 $("#zipcodechange").click(function() {  
  $.fancybox({
    href : "#zipcode",
      helpers: { overlay: { css: { 'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)' } } },
    afterClose : function(){ 
      $.fancybox.close();
    }
  }); // fancybox 
 }); // click

$("#zipcode").bind("submit", function() {
  $.fancybox.showLoading(); 
  $.ajax({
      url    : "map-5.php",
      type: "POST",       
      data: $("#zipcode").serializeArray(),
      success: function(responseText) {     
      $.fancybox.open({
          content   : '<iframe id="myFrame" class="fancybox-iframe"
        frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" src="about:blank"></iframe>',    
          width     : '70%',
          height    : '700px',
          // fitToView: false, 
          autoSize: false, // 
          closeClick: false,
          openEffect: 'elastic',
          closeEffect: 'fade',
          helpers: {overlay: {css: {'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)' } } },
          afterShow : function() {
              var oIframe = document.getElementById('myFrame');
              var iframeDoc = (
                               oIframe.contentWindow.document ||
                               oIframe.contentDocument );  iframeDoc.open(); 
              iframeDoc.write(responseText);
              iframeDoc.close();
          },
          afterClose: function () {
              location.reload();
              return;
          }
        }); // fancybox
        } // success    
  }); // ajax
  return false;
 }); // bind
}); // ready 
</script>
```

Comment: I got the map to show using chrome on my galaxy s3. granted it wasn't a map of my location I used  ut the map did infact display

Comment: check your console :error occurs "showAddress is not defined"

Comment: Hi @harshit Tailor , thankyou for your reply,i defined the showAddress on another php file(map-5.php). please help me..

Comment: Did you not include the 'other php file' in this one?

Answer (score 0):

Sir, you define `showAddress` in 81 line but call it in 17 line. These lines executes synchroniously, what mean you have to define function first. I am a bit surprised how this could work in Firefox.